# ExtJS/Javascript: How the function for clicking event actually works?

Tags: javascript, extjs

sorry if my question sounds stupid but I would like to ask that how the function for clicking event actually works? I mean how the parameters are passed to the called function. For example in this [ExtJS Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2566&view/editor), in the View when we click the delete button, it will call the `onDelete` function which be defined in the Controller:

```
onDelete: function (t, rowid, colid, item, evt, rec) {
        var store = rec.store;

        store.remove(rec);
        store.sync();
    }
```

What i dont really understand here is how these parameters (t, rowid, colid, evt, rec) are passed to the function definition while in the view we called only the name of the function `onDelete`, nothing else. So where these parameters come from?

Any answer is appreciated and please dont vote my question down insted ignore it if you think it is a stupid one but i just ask what i really dont understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameter are passed by the ExtJS library. This allows you to concentrate on the feature you want to achieve (delete a record) instead of writing code to find the clicked row record before doing the real work.

Comment: Hi Yann, thank you for your answer. This means it depends on which kind of element that I clicked, then there will have specific function library for that  event, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. If you [add a listener to a DOM element](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/events.html) for example, the [`click`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#event-click) event will send three parameters to the callback: `e` (The Ext.event.Event encapsulating the DOM event), `t` (The target of the event) and `eOpts` (The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener).